# Отдать изображение с другого сайта по относительному пути

Tags: .htaccess

2 сайта, на 1 хранятся изображения, на втором необходимо данные изображения отдать

На втором сайте, если обращаться по относительному пути к примеру

```
/uploads/img_m.webp
```

Изображение будет не найдено.

Вопрос в том, возможно ли это реализовать, к примеру путем настроек через htaccess? На втором сайте....

Comment: они на одном сервере лежат? там nginх есть? или только apache?

Comment: nginх,  блин, не хватает пару символов для комента)

Comment: Сайты на одном сервере лежат?